# Animated image transition with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Trying to wrap my head around the HTML5 canvas, I thought I'd create an image carousel, where images would be changed by an opacity gradient sweep, i.e. the same thing as in my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Schlaus/dpn5jeg8/4/), only with canvas. I managed to come up with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Schlaus/9zxtd1cf/), but I can't understand at all what's happening, or rather, why nothing is.

Here's the code:

```
var outputCanvas = document.getElementById('output'),
    ctx = outputCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    eWidth = 50,
    speed = 5,
    cWidth = 480,
    img = document.getElementById('newimg'),
    x = 0, y = 0,
    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

function draw() {
    console.log(x);
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, 0, x+eWidth, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}

function animate() {
    if (x < 480) {
        x += Math.floor((cWidth / 1000) * speed);
        console.log(x);
        draw();
        reqAnimFrame(animate);
    }
}

reqAnimFrame(animate);
```

Calling the `draw` function by itself it seems to work, but once I start firing it with `RequestAnimationFrame` it just stops working. The gradient gets drawn once, but even though `x` is updated in the animation loop, the gradient stays put.

I guess there's something I'm just not getting about how canvas and `RequestAnimationFrame` work.

Note that I'm not looking for a script or library that does the same thing, but rather I'm hoping to actually understand how canvas works, and in particular why my script doesn't.

Comment: For one thing, `reqAnimFrame(animate);` should be `requestAnimationFrame(animate);`

Comment: @markE Sorry, I forgot to paste in the bit where `reqAnimFrame` is defined. I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: What exactly does `console.log(x)` output?

Comment: What is the expected result of `draw()` ? Thanks

Comment: @soktinpk The output is as expected, increasing ints from 0 to 480.

Comment: @guest271314 Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Schlaus/dpn5jeg8/4/ for a demonstration, I can't really put it into words better than I already have :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here's one way to do a wipe transition between 2 images using Canvas Compositing:**

Original Images (before & after):

[image][image]

Canvas during gradient wipe-transition between the images:

[image]

- create a transparent-to-opaque gradient that is eWidth pixels wide.
- clear the canvas
- draw the gradient
- fill all pixels to the right of the gradient with opaque
- draw the first image with `source-in` compositing.  This will display the first image only where the gradient has non-transparent pixels.
- draw the second image with 'destination-over' compositing. This will display the second image "under" the existing first image.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var cw,ch;
var x=0;
var eWidth=100;

var img1=new Image();
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sailboat.png";
function start(){

  cw=canvas.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=img.height;

  img1.onload=function(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };
  img1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sailboat1.png";

}


function draw() {

  // create gradient
  gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x-eWidth,0, x,0);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0,0,0, 0)");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0,0,0, 1)");

  // save the unaltered canvas context
  ctx.save();

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // gradient zone
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(x-eWidth,0,eWidth,ch);

  // fully original right of x
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(x,0,cw,ch);

  // original image with gradient "dissolve" on left

  // set compositing to source-in
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // revealed image 
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
  ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);

  // restore the context to its unaltered state
  ctx.restore();
}


function animate() {
  if (x<cw+eWidth){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }
  x+=5;
  draw();
}

$('#again').click(function(){
  x=0;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);    
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Wipe transition between images using canvas</h4>
<button id=again>Again</button><br><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: A very thorough answer, thank you! My original code didn't work because I was using `globalCompositeOperation` wrong.